# Airflow folder structure for effective source control

Tags: python, airflow

What is the recommended airflow project structure for better version control? I have something like this

```
|-- my_project
    |-- dags
        |-- my_data_pipeline_dag.py
        |-- lib
            |-- my_python_etl.py
```

What would be a better way of doing this to be efficient?
I have tried a couple of things but not satisfied with the approach. Any thoughts or industry standards are appreciated.

> 1) I manually copy the dags folder from the version control repo ie
>   `cp ~/my_project/dags ~/airflow/dags`.(trust me am not proud of this)
>
> 2) Pushed a folder named `dags` instead of `my_project` to my Bit
>   bucket repo. Even this doesn't seem like a good idea.

I would really appreciate it if you could point me to something or give some concrete answers to improve this situation.

Something tells me Docker is the answer for this.Any thoughts on this is also much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/managing-airflow-code/) , I follow this template for my projects:

```
── dags                        
   ── example-dag.py
   ── redshift_transforms.py
── Dockerfile
── include                     
   ── sql
       ── transforms.sql
── packages.txt                
── plugins                    
   ── example-plugin.py
── requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of remote access to the `dags` folder in your runtime environment? You could set up a build pipeline which pushes the content of the dag folder on commits to a git branch. For example: if you dags folder was a folder in a Google Cloud Storage or AWS bucket, you could mount this bucket using a fuse filesystem. You build pipeline would then push the dags to that folder. See an example on how this is accomplished using Google Cloud Build here: https://www.web3us.com/how-guides/sync-github-repo-your-gcp-composer